# How to display Bootstrap toast when page loads?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have added a query string param to my index with the intention that it can show toasts for errors and such. Though I'm struggling to make it show when the page loads.

I'm using the `$('#toast').toast('show');` method. It works when I assign it as a button's onclick, but not directly in a script tag or in miscellaneous JQuery events, including $(document).ready() and $(window).load().

Comment: Any error in console? Can you not debug and see if toast() even exists at the point you are trying to show it? Most likely the toast() method is not loaded yet and it should show it in the console error. Press F12 to see developer tools/console.

Comment: That was it, jQuery wasn't loaded yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, jQuery isn't loaded before the end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = (event) => {
    var toastLiveExample = document.getElementById('liveToast')
    var toast = new bootstrap.Toast(toastLiveExample)
    toast.show()
}
```